# Simple simple content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can some one help?

I am looking for a content slider that can hold images and text and has dot navigation.

I have searched for so many on the net but nothing that is simple.

Guys honestly I have looked and looked, I looked at Questions that may already have been answered. I have also looked at the Similar Questions on the right hand side.

I have found this http://jsbin.com/uhowak/2 but i don't want it to whizz back to the first image i want it to be loop.

Please can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Twitter bootstrap carousel might work for you. See the "wrap" option for cycling. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: codecanyon.net has plenty, you have to pony up the dough though

Comment: @bumperbox can i put content in it? Thanks mate this is a help.

Comment: yes i can thank you bumperbox

Comment: @bumperbox this is a really silly but how do i download this, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try twitter bootstrap carousel

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

You can download it from this page

http://getbootstrap.com/

Unzip the file, you can either include the whole bootstrap library, which will be in

```
zipfile/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

or just include the carousel only

```
zipfile/js/carousel.js
```

You will also need to include the jquery library for the bootstrap js to work

http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help.